# Can i click on a flash movie embedded in a webpage and remove it from the DOM?

Tags: jquery, flash

I have a flash movie embedded on a webpage, it's an intro of sorts, when the movie has finished it removes itself from the DOM but I also want this functionality on flash movie click.

so far to remove it after it's finished playing I'm using

```
function overlayRemove(){
        $(".welcome-overlay #flashContent").fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            $("#nav_1254390").css("visibility","visible");
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout("overlayRemove()",7000);

});
```

I've tried adding this

```
$(".welcome-overlay #flashContent").click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $("#nav_1254390").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

but it never gets called. I also tried adding the click event to the body and it worked everywhere but not over the top of the flash movie.

Am i missing something?
thanks for any replies

Answer (score 0):

you need to add something to the flash using external interface so that when you click on the flash it can communicate with the js/dom etc.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

So you have been removing the flash movie clip when the on 7 sec timeout.

however, when you click on the flash movie, the click will be handled by flash, and the click event will not come to javascript.

To remove it on click, you need to edit the flash movie, and put an ExternalInterface call through which flash will communicate with javascript and javascript will then remove the flash movie.

CLICK->FLASH->ExternallInterface call->JAVASCRIPT-> remove flash